# AVSynchronizedLayer: Layer contents fades out

Tags: ios, avfoundation, calayer

I'm using AVSynchronizedLayer to show the animations added to a video. I have a custom CALayer which contains text drawn using coretext. I will add this custom CALayer with coretext to another CALayer as sublayer. And finally this layer is added to AVSynchroziedLayer.

```
// initilaise annotation layer

CALayer *textLayer = annotation.drawinglayer;// initialise custom layer

textLayer.position = annotation.location;

textLayer.beginTime = 1e-100;

[self.annotationLayer addSublayer:textLayer];

// set annotationlayer frame

//add this annotation layer as sublayer of AVSynchronizedLayer.
```

So when I play the video it works fine as expected. When I seek forward, it works as expected, but when I pause and seek backword the content of textlayer (text or lines) fades whereas the layer remains. Only content disappears, if it has sublayers it will not fade . I just want to place text for a particular time range.But it fades when I seek back. Please help.